# How to read an array of Structures in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create an array of CGPoint from an NSArray whose each entry is NSPoint

```
 NSArray *points = [_terrain getPathPoints];
 CCLOG(@"Terrain Points=%@",points);
```

Output in log:

```
Terrain Points=(
    "NSPoint: {-3.4324746, 70.220947}",
    "NSPoint: {-3.9852712, 70.136444}",
    "NSPoint: {-4.3119373, 70.058411}",
    "NSPoint: {-4.4321384, 69.986282}",
    "NSPoint: {-4.3655362, 69.919479}",
    "NSPoint: {-4.131794, 69.857513}",
    "NSPoint: {-3.7505748, 69.799774}"
)
```

getPathPoints is a method from a third party tool that I am using. This method returns an array of NSPoint. How can I create an array of CGPoint from the above data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing are most likely `NSValue` objects created from `CGPoint` structs (you cannot put a `CGPoint` or `NSPoint` directly into an `NSArray`). The fact that they log as `NSPoint` may be a bit confusing (a vestige from the Mac, `NSPoint` is essentially the same as `CGPoint`), but you can easily convert such a "boxed" value back to a `CGPoint` with the `CGPointValue` method, e.g.

```
NSArray *points = [_terrain getPathPoints];
NSValue *lastPointValue = [points lastObject];
CGPoint lastPoint = [lastPointValue CGPointValue];
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/QuartzOpenGL/QuartzOpenGL.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH211-BAADHIAF)?

> **Graphics Type Conversions**
>
> When going back and forth between Cocoa and Quartz code, some conversion of data types may be necessary. Table 9-1 shows the Cocoa equivalents of some basic Quartz types.
>
> ```
> Table 9-1  Simple data-type conversions
>     Cocoa type       Quartz type
>       NSRect           CGRect
>       NSPoint          CGPoint
>       NSSize           CGSize
> ```
>
> Although in each case the structure layout is the same, you cannot pass the Quartz data type directly to a method expecting the Cocoa type. To convert, you must cast from one type to another, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> NSRect cocoaRect = *(NSRect*)&myCGRect;
> ```